# Is it possible to have collision on a child object moves its parent in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, collision

I'm attempting to develop a 2.5D fighting game in Unity, and I've gotten to the point of attempting to make basic collision between players function. I'm attempting to do so via collision boxes like those seen in the video here: (4:01 if the timestamp doesn't work)

https://youtu.be/m5yRLhAx4Ro?t=241

What I have attempted to do in order to replicate this system of collision is to make a collision box prefab with a dynamic rigidbody and box collider. A script instantiates a new one as a child of the player and destroys any existing ones whenever the collision box's size and position need to be changed. However, I've found that this does not work. I can get the players to collide with each other, but when I disable that collision by putting the parents on a layer that doesn't collide with any others, the collision boxes themselves will just phase through each other along with their parent objects, the players.

What I want is a system in which the players will be responsible for their movement, but the child objects (the collision boxes) will function as the players' colliders. If anyone knows a way of doing this, or any other way of achieving this sort of system, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [Fixed Joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html) on the child object then connect it with the parent rigidbody.